# why does IntelliJ IDEA debug complain a package does not exist while it's there

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, trino

I'm new to Java and IntelliJ IDEA.

Trying to understand a Java Maven package (https://github.com/prestosql/presto/tree/337, release version 337). After I import the project into IntelliJ IDEA, I tried to debug a [test](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/337/presto-geospatial/src/test/java/io/prestosql/plugin/geospatial/TestGeoFunctions.java#L120-L125) :

[image]

But then it complains a package doesn't exist while it's there as highlighted, how to make IDEA find the package, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to execute this command

> mvn clean install

to clean your project, and get all your project dependencies

Comment: what about this trouble appears only running tests? i've upgraded to 2020.3 and faced this issue.